# c# windows forms control in panel not centered

Tags: c#, winforms

I have an issue with my c# application.

I have a panel for item detail and a form that i add as a control to the panel.
This is how i fill the panel:

```
private void initDetailPanel()
{
    _detail = new FinanceItemDetail() { Dock = DockStyle.Fill, TopLevel = false };
    financeItemDetailPanel.Controls.Add(_detail);
    _detail.Show();
}
```

the detail form is the same size as the financeItemDetail panel. I used this method before on some other parts of my app, but this time, it does not work correctly and it seems to somehow grow the size of the form:
[image]
(in the form, the controls are centered)

I tried to get some answers via chatgpt, which suggested anchoring but that didnt work. I tried to play around with the panel and form properties (like autosize, maximum size etc) but i think there must be something that i'm missing.

Thanks in advance for any advice!

Comment: When is initDetailPanel called? Before or after the form is shown?

Comment: Your Form is probably scaling to the default `Font` and its *Parent* may have a different, larger Font that its child Controls inherit -- You should build UserControls instead of Forms

Comment: @Ralf its called in the main form Load function, so i'm assuming before?

Comment: Just for a test you may try moving it to the shown event.

Comment: @Jimi Oh my god, you're totally right. Thank you so much! I will definitely change to userControl, i should've been doing that from the beginning.

Comment: Answers from ChatGPT? Thats a good one 